# jQuery attr using img src from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, attr

My goal is to loop through a list of objects and display the image src and name in each column loop method but have been unsuccessful. I have seen the attr("src", "image src") method but not used in a loop. I may also be using the wrong class in the html...Am I approaching this the right way? I am new to jQuery. Thank you for any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
            <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:</h2>
            <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
                <div class="col-lg-3 char-img"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 char-img"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 char-img"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 char-img"></div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
//Objects
var hansolo = {
    name: "Han Solo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/hansolo.jpg",
}

var chewy = {
    name: "Chewy",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/chewy.jpg",
}

var jabba = {
    name: "Jabba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/jabba.jpg",
}

var greedo = {
    name: "Greedo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/greedo.jpg",
}

var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, greedo];

for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    var charOptions = $("<charOptions>");
    charOptions
        .addClass( "char-img char-text")
        .attr("src", choices[i].src)
        .text(choices[i].name);        
    $(".charOptions").append(charOptions);
    console.log(charOptions);
}
```

Comment: Your asking for our opinion or?

Comment: What is `charOptions` in `<charOptions>`?

Comment: @Satpal just loaded the html

Comment: create correct element `var charOptions = $("<img>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to loop through the list of objects and display the image src and name in each column?

Firstly, remove all the .col-lg-* in your HTML markup, as we should create this dynamically.

Then, just loop through your object and create the relevant HTML objects that you want to append.

```
var charOptionsRow = $('#charOptions');
$.each(choices, function(index, choice) {
  // Create a new div.col-lg-3 to be appended to row.
  var charOptionCol = $('<div>')
    .addClass('char-option col-lg-3');

  // Append image to col.
  var charImg = $('<img>')
    .addClass('char-img')
    .attr('src', choice.src);
  charOptionCol.append(charImg);

  // Append text to col.
  var charText = $('<h5>')
    .addClass('char-text')
    .text(choice.name);
  charOptionCol.append(charText);

  // Append column to row.
  charOptionsRow.append(charOptionCol);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are trying to create an [**img**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag

Also `img` is a self closing tag & a void element.you may not able to add `text` to it. I guess you are looking for `alt` property

```
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) { tag
    // creating img
    var charOptions = $("<img>");
    charOptions
        .addClass( "char-img char-text")
        .attr("src", choices[i].src)
        .alt(choices[i].name);     
    // use id selector since there is no dom with class charOptions   
    $("#charOptions").append(charOptions);
    console.log(charOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery

//Objects
var hansolo = {
name: "Han Solo",
attack: 10,
hp: 20,
counter: 0,
src: "assets/images/hansolo.jpg",
}

var chewy = {
name: "Chewy",
attack: 10,
hp: 20,
counter: 0,
src: "assets/images/chewy.jpg",
}

var jabba = {
name: "Jabba",
attack: 10,
hp: 20,
counter: 0,
src: "assets/images/jabba.jpg",
}

var greedo = {
name: "Greedo",
attack: 10,
hp: 20,
counter: 0,
src: "assets/images/greedo.jpg",
}

var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, greedo];

$(choices).each(function(){
        console.log(this.src);
        var div = "<div  class='col-lg-3 char-img'><img 
src="+this.src+" /></div>"
        $('#charOptions').append(div);
});







html

<div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
        <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:
</h2>
        <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 char-img"  style="width:800px; color:red;" >a</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 char-img">b</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 char-img">c</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 char-img">d</div>
        </div>
```

> **https://jsfiddle.net/sunilsoma/p111hyk3/**